# Custom Route for Laravel Nested Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am making a Laravel app with url structure as follows

```
/users/{userid}/pets/{petid}
```

I want to make a custom route for

```
/users/{userid}/pets/seefavoritepets
```

But I can't figure out how to do it.  I currently have:

`Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('users.pets', "PetsController");`

But it can't figure out how to make the cutom route.  I tried

`Route::get('users.pets/seefavoritepets', function() {
    return "getting favorite pets!";
});`

to no avail.  All help appreciated

Comment: just do `Route::get('/users/{userid}/pets/seefavoritepets'`

Comment: Try refactoring your idea. I assume favorite pets is a relationship between user and pets. So having `favoritepets` after pets is like saying `/user/1/pets/1/favoritepets` which is wrong because that is saying favorite pets of pet 1 of user 1. Which is already defining the relationship between user and pet so I am also going to assume favorite pets is either of the pet's user has or is a general route not associated to a user.

Comment: The Route::get('/users/{userid}/pets/seefavoritepets') is exactly what I needed.  Don't know how I missed that!  Additionally your comment about rethinking logic seems good to me too.  Thanks!